# What are the technical differences between using Laravel Sanctum vs tymon/jwt-auth for API authentication in a Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, laravel-sanctum

So i was wondering about which to use for authentication of APIs and what are the technical differences between using Laravel Sanctum vs tymon/jwt-auth for API authentication in a Laravel application?.

I'm working on project which has laravel as backend. So Admin panel and APIs are gonna managed by Laravel. I already applied custom authentication & RBAC authorization but now i'm confused like which package should i use for API authentication "Laravel Sanctum" or "tymon/jwt-auth". which will be good practice? and will be easy to maintain?

Are there any pros/cons of both packages i should consider before using them in my project?

I have used both sanctum & tymon/jwt-auth in my practice projects. so i don't have issue regarding  using either of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some differences,

**Laravel Sanctum:**

- Easy API login with cookies and sessions.
- Works smoothly with Laravel, adding security.

**tymon/jwt-auth:**

- Customize your own login with tokens.
- Faster, no Laravel dependency.
- No need of cookies or sessions.

Decide based on how easy or customized you want your login to be.

Comment: I would add that Sanctum also has tokens (not only session based auth) that are easier to implement than jwt-auth and lighter (only 40 characters)